# How to recognize or identify an object made by a factory

Tags: javascript

What would be the best way to reproduce the `instanceof` functionality for an object made by a factory ?

Example:

```js
class Cat {
   constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
const tom = new Cat('tom');
tom instanceof Cat // true
```

VS

```js
const makeCat = (name) => ({
 name
})
const garfield = makeCat('garfield');
// ???
```

What would be the best way to identify the garfield object as a "cat" since it was made by makeCat ?

Comment: Have the factory return a Cat? `const makeCat = name => new Cat(name)`?

Comment: The Cat class wouldn't exist in the factory scenario. That's pretty much the idea behind having factories, not depending on classes if you don't need to. In this example, I wouldn't need any functionality specific to classes, I just want to create an object with a name, and recognize that this object has been made by the cat factory, and therefore is a cat. Don't really know if I'm clear :p

Comment: Ohh I see now you want identify the factory that made the cat. `return new MakeCat()` after `MakeCat.prototype = Cat.prototype` should set the class hierarchy and when you do instance of, you `x instanceof MakeCat`

Comment: Not exactly. In the class scenario, I can identify `tom` as being a instance of Cat. So I know for sure that it has been made by the Class Cat, therefore it has all the attributes and methods of a cat. In the factory scenario, I have no way to identify `garfield` as being a cat, because the factory will just produce an object, therefore I can't seem to find a way to recognize it "officially" as a Cat. The only way without using Symbols for example, would be to check "Has garfield a name ? Yes. So it can be a cat.". Hope I'm clearer.

Comment: That's why you set the factory prototype to Cats prototype, this let's you identify it as a Cat and as a Cat made by MakeCat. You can also check for the key`name`, but that won't tell you it's type and instanceof won't work when testing for cat AND any object with a name could be a cat by that logic but that doesn't make sense - dogs have a name, can they be a cat?

Comment: "any object with a name could be a cat" that's exactly my point. The problem is that the Cat prototype doesn't exist with a factory.

Comment: did you mean "...to identify the garfield object as an **object** made by makeCat"? Because the thing made by makeCat is not a Cat.

Comment: @Wyck That's it yes. By definition, if an object is returned by makeCat, it's a "cat". Not an instance of Cat, sure, but the purpose of the factory is to produce objects that are "cats". If I can identify an object made by makeCat, I can assume it's a cat.

Comment: This smells like XY.  You're using a factory pattern that embraces "it doesn't matter what kind it is" then you to know what kind it is.  :/  Why do you want to do this?  If it's something like recycling the object back to its creator, then include a recycle method with each object.

Comment: That's not the purpose of a factory. The purpose of a factory is to hide the implementation details of some object's construction from the object's consumer.

Comment: So `const makeCat = name => Object.create({isCat: true}, { name: {value: name} })`? Or `const makeCat = name => Object.create({ type: 'cat' }, { name: {value: name} })`?

Comment: @RichardBarker, Chop just included a sentence that said "the purpose of the factory is..." and they are the asker, so you shouldn't strawman like that.  The previous comment acknowledged that the purpose was _to produce objects that are "cats"_.  Replace "cats" with "ducks" and you literally have [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  There is some polymorphic behaviour desired here, I'm hoping Chop will let us know what it is.

Comment: @RichardBarker I don't need to "hide object types". I want to keep the advantages of a factory (especially scope closures) because it fits more my project needs. My goal is just to be sure that if I create a "makeZoo" tomorrow, I have a way to recognize that an object made by makeCat will be allowed in my Zoo.

Comment: @rayhatfield Of course, I could do it manually. I even thought of creating an exportable Symbol that would allow me to recognize a ""private"" property. But it feels hacky (and it probably is)

Comment: @Wyck Thanks a lot for the duck-typing reference, didn't know it, and I feel like it pretty much sums up my idea yes !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it feels while discussing in the comments like there is no "best practice" solution for this (without using a class at least, which I don't want to), this would probably be my implementation for this purpose:

```js
const cat = Symbol('cat');

export const makeCat = (name) => { 
    return {
        [cat]: true,
        name
    }
};

export const isCat = (obj) => obj[cat];
```

```js
import { makeCat, isCat } from './CatFactory.js';

const garfield = makeCat('garfield');
const tom = { cat: true, name: 'tom' };

isCat(garfield); // true
isCat(tom); // false
```

It's the less hacky way I found to recreate any sort of 'certainty' while trying to identify an object made by my factory and without making it possible to create a cat by mistake or even duck-typing and without polluting a console.log of the object created for example.